# How to change onclick of element onclick without immediately running?

Tags: javascript

When I click a button I want to change the onclick of the html tag.

Here's my code:

JavaScript:

```
function reset() {
  //some code 1
}

function hit() {
  //some code 2
  document.getElementById("htmlId").onclick = reset;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id = "htmlId">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width height=device-height">
  </head>  
  <body>
    <button id = "btn1" onclick = "hit();" class = "btn">Hit</button>
    <script src="script.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click the button I expect for some code 2 to execute and on my next click for some code 1 to execute. But when I click both some code 1 and some code 2 execute immediately.

If you add an empty onclick before it, reset(); still runs.

JavaScript:

```
function empty() {
}

function hit() {
  //some code 2
  document.getElementById("htmlId").onclick = empty;
  document.getElementById("htmlId").onclick = reset;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're targeting an ID of `htmlId` but your button has an id of `btn1`.

Comment: The htmlId is for the entire html block.

Comment: Well that points to the issue I suppose then. The button is a child of the HTML block, therefore clicking on the button triggers a click on both the HTML block *and* the button. You're not doing anything to remove the first click event, you're just adding another one.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the extra call then?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "extra" call, but you can either set the *button*'s click event instead of the HTML block (thus overwriting the original event), *or*, remove the button's click event by doing `document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = '';`

Comment: I mean can you stop the html call or make the html call go first?

Comment: Events bubble upwards, therefore the button's event fires first, and moves outward, hitting `<html>` last. This is known as event propagation, or more specifically, [event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture). You can stop this behavior using [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here that are interesting to address:

1. You have JavaScript in HTML attributes which is no longer considered good practice.
2. Dealing with the whole HTML element *and* a button inside of that element that you want to manage will lead to *bubble* and *capture* issues
3. You want to change the listeners on elements but you are using the `onclick` property while modern practice is to use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

Here are my suggestions:

- Put all of the JavaScript listeners in the JS file; your HTML should be free of JavaScript.
- Use `addEventListener` instead of assigning to `onclick`.
- Because event listener adding and removing can be tricky, consider using a variable that records whether the button has been pressed. Then your html click listener does a reset only if in that state.

So something like (code is not tested, but should get you started):

```
let shouldReset = false;

document.getElementById("btnId").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  shouldReset = true;
  e.stopPropagation(); // so the big HTML element doesn't get it
}

document.getElementById("htmlId").addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (shouldReset) {
    reset();
  }
}
```

So clicks on the html element do nothing unless the button has been first clicked. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create another function, and attach that once the first function has executed:

```
function hit() {

    // you initial hit() function's code here

    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = '';

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', function() { 
            /* define the next function */ 
        })
    }), 1);
};
```

or to better apply to your case :

```
function reset() { ... }

function hit() {

    // you initial hit() function's code here

    document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = '';

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener('click', reset)
    }, 1);
};
```

This can be improved in many ways, but for the scope of your question it should do just fine.